# QNetworkReply "unable to write"

Tags: c++, qt

Im trying to upload some data with the QNetworkManager and getting the response in QNetworkReply. Then i test, if the reply was an error and if, i print the error message and i dont understand the result.

```
if(reply->error()) {
        qDebug() << reply->error() << reply->errorString();
}
```

Result:

```
QNetworkReply::UnknownNetworkError "Unable to write"
```

What does the errorString "Unable to write" mean. Is this a return message from the Server or where does it come from?

I open QNetworkManager in a loop, is it a problem with opening to many Manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't construct QNetworkManager in loop, even use only one manager for an application as possible. It is not for single request. There is QNetworkRequest which ressembles request already.